# Return variable from class defined in another thread

Tags: java, multithreading, audio

I'm programming an audio visualizer. To sync the data that is to be displayed to the music itself, I need to get the clip's/player's current position in the audio file by calling `clip.getMicrosecondPosition()` / `player.getPosition()`. This is working fine for the clip. The problem is that I need to define the player object in another thread since calling `player.play()` halts all execution in the current thread until the file is played until the end. `Player` is a class from the MP3SPI library (`javazoom.jl.player.Player`).

Code:

```
public class AudioTools implements Runnable {

public File file;
public boolean isMP3 = false;
public Player player;
public Clip clip;

public AudioTools(File file) {
    this.file = file;
    determineFilyType();
}   

private void determineFileType() {
    if (file.getAbsolutePath().endsWith(".mp3")) {
        this.isMP3 = true;
    } else if (file.getAbsolutePath().endsWith(".wav")) {
        this.isMP3 = false;
    } else {
        System.err.println("Invalid File Type!");
        System.exit(0);
    }

}

public void play() {
    if (isMP3) {
        Thread t = new Thread(this);
        t.start(); // play MP3 using Player class
    } else {
        playWav(file); // play WAV using Clip class
    }

}

protected void playMP3(File file){
    try {
        player = new Player(new FileInputStream(file));
        player.play();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Invalid MP3 File!");
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(0);
    }

}

@Override
public void run() {
    playMP3(file);
}

private void playWav(File file) {
    try {
        AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
        DataLine.Info dataInfo = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, null);
        clip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(dataInfo);
        clip.open(ais);
        clip.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.err.println("Invalid .wav file!");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

}

Main class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

File file = new File(/*PATH_TO_FILE_HERE*/);
AudioTools at = new AudioTools(file);
at.play();
// at.clip.getMicrosecondPosition() works here if loaded file is .wav.
// at.player.getPosition() returns null if loaded file is .mp3.
}
```

From the main class, I'd like to be able to get the player's current position. Currently, trying this will return null.

Any helpful comments are appreciated. I've asked a similar question before, this edit made the question a bit more clear and shorter. 

EDIT: Should contain all code necissary to run the example.

Comment: An MCVE might help.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if i completed understood your question but i will try to explain some things to you.

Lets say you have a class `Clip` where at a random time of 300ms to 1000ms (just for example) plays one second of the clip and sets the variable `currentLength` which is what you want to get from other thread.

```
public class Clip implements Runnable {

    private int clipLength;

    private volatile int currentLength;

    public Clip(int clipLength) {
        this.clipLength = clipLength;
    }

    public void run() {

        while (currentLength <= clipLength) {
            try {
                currentLength += 1;
                Thread.sleep(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(300, 1000 + 1));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    public int getCurrentLength() {
        return currentLength;
    }

    public void setCurrentLength(int currentLength) {
        this.currentLength = currentLength;
    }

}
```

Also lets say you have a class `Player` and what it does is that takes the clip object and after some time it requests the current length of it.

```
public class Player implements Runnable {

    private Clip clip;

    public Player(Clip clip) {
        this.clip = clip;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println(clip.getCurrentLength());
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            System.out.println(clip.getCurrentLength());
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println(clip.getCurrentLength());
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            System.out.println(clip.getCurrentLength());
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Also we have a Main class containg the start of the program where we create a Clip object and pass it to the to runnable class.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Clip clip = new Clip(60);
        Thread thread = new Thread(clip);
        thread.start();
        Thread threadPlayer = new Thread(new Player(clip));
        threadPlayer.start();

    }

}
```

I think this is what you asked for but before implement it to your program you should read about [atomic access and volatile keyword](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html) and also is good to know about the [Java memory model.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_memory_model)

Comment: Thanks! Interesting read, although it didn't quite answered my question.

Answer (score 0):

Solved using a different approach that isn't even part of the question. I already had an array of the decrypted audio data that I can turn into an AudioInputStream that Clip is able to play.